# Is Reading of a clocking block output in system verilog is allowed?

Tags: system-verilog

```
module input2 (output [3:0] out1, out2, input [3:0] in1, input clk);

clocking c_clk @(posedge clk);
output #2ns out1, temp = in1[1:0];
input in1;
endclocking

clocking d_clk @(posedge clk);
output out2;
input #2ns svar = in1[3:2];
endclocking

assign out1 = c_clk.temp ^ 4'b1101;
assign out2 = d_clk.svar + in1;

endmodule
```

my tool is giving an error that `"Reading of a clocking block output (c_clk.temp ) is not allowed."` I have not found any standard for this statement.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The [1800-2012](http://go.mentor.com/get-1800) standard says in 14.3 Clocking block declaration

> It shall be illegal to read the value of any clockvar whose
>   clocking_direction is output.

The reason is an output has no defined sampling semantics. An inout does.

Comment: Why are is your link pointed to your blog post and not the LRM itself from IEEE? http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf

Comment: @Greg, It's a short link that's easy for me to remember, plus I want to get the message out that this a free standard, unlike most other IEEE standards.